# Why is my Largest Contenful Paint so much larger than my page load time?

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm optimising a WordPress website for page speed. To do so, I use the Google PageSpeed Insights to find my weak points. It is about the website [goedkopewebsitezzp.nl](https://goedkopewebsitezzp.nl/).

A few of the measures I've taken:

- every page is cached
- I optimised every image with ShortPixel and they're served as WebP
- all CSS and JS is minified and combined using a plugin. Unfortunately the CSS is still split into three files, but I can't find a way to compile that again into one.
- I use the Cloudflare CDN
- jQuery is loaded from Cloudflare CDN.

My current page speed score is about 65-68. The biggest 'red' factor is the Largest Contentful Paint.

[image]

I currently am a bit stuck how to proceed with the LCP and I don't understand why this value is so large. If you [visit the website](https://goedkopewebsitezzp.nl/), it is quite fast. My experience is about max 2 seconds with empty caches etc.

How come that the LCP has a value of slightly less than 9 seconds, when my page loads way faster? The LCP element is the first bold header (h1 element).

I think that there is something not going alright with the theme. I also have the same problem on an other [website](https://proviewinterieurs.nl/), where I also used the same theme. The LCP there is also about 9 seconds.

Perhaps the animation is the cause, but that only takes about 200 ms. I already tried disabling it, but there weren't any numerous improvements.

I'm really stuck how to proceed with this, and as the LCP counts for 25% of the total score, I would really like to get it down to a few seconds.

Thanks a lot in advance. All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Wordpress and Cloudflare are loading external files which must be parsed before the page is rendered (contentful paint). Why do you need Wordpress in the first place? Can you get a hosting account and then host the files you need locally on the hosting server? That would improve rendering times significantly while being more secure.

Comment: my guess: the h1 is flagged because you are loading an font from google and this takes some time. also you dont have the property `font-display: swap` on your fonts

Comment: Hi @SJacks will consider that. There's no obvious reason to use WordPress; it's just that I'm used to using WordPress. Do you have a guide or sth on how to export plain HTML files etc from WP?

Comment: @SJacks having though better about it, is serving cached files through Cloudflare CDN not the same as not using WP? A reason is perhaps that I regularly want to add pages and doing that with WP and Elementor is way less labour intensive than coding everything by hand or updating a bunch of HTML files regularly.

Comment: Hey @Ifaruki thanks for the suggestion. I checked, but as far as I know the rule is applied.

Comment: @ralphsmit yes, using external frameworks is less labour intensive but as you can see that comes at a cost. Files are only cached once they have been loaded and stored locally by a user. It's in your interest to serve up all the necessary data as quickly as possible to reduce the bounce rate. If you are capable of writing your own code and hosting your own files and if you have the time, it's the best possible solution as it will give you the most amount of control over loading times.

Comment: @SJacks that's perhaps indeed the best idea. Have you got any experience with a WP export plugin like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-wp-page-to-static-html/?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. Aside from jQuery I only code in raw format, never used any frameworks like Wordpress before, never had to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Speed Index

Speed Index is quite complicated to explain here, so I will link to [this article](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-index) and the [original speed index that Lighthouse Speed Index is based on](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest-docs/blob/master/user/Metrics/SpeedIndex.md)

But in essence it compares a load of images of the site along a timeline as it loads. When it finds it has reached a certain "completeness" compared to the final page design it uses that time for the speed index.

Now when you apply your full page white cover to hide all the loading going on that creates a paint event that is the whole page and this slightly skews your Speed Index.

The figures also get skewed by long animations. You say 200ms but the performance trace thinks it is more like 400ms which matches the following item:-

```
#ambition_body.fade_in_out {
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

So your speed index may be slightly out but if anything it is **lower** than it is in reality as your white cover stays way past 3.4 seconds when I apply [network throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md#network-throttling) and [CPU throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md#cpu-throttling) to match Lighthouse (the engine behind Page Speed Insights).

**note:** This is why you see 9 seconds vs your observed 2 seconds time, Lighthouse is taking into account throttling on the network and CPU as per the linked article information in the previous paragraph.

### Largest Contentful Paint

This does happen much later, it appears there is a slight shift in the page just as the fadeout occurs. As you can see on this performance trace it happens right before the final image in the trace (the LCP line is the one to look at).

[image: trace showing when LCP occurs]

This appears to be from something strange happening, perhaps with your menu.

I turned on "paint flashing" under the "rendering" tab in Developer tools and just as the page is fading into view there is a strange flash towards the top left and then the whole page seems to repaint.

I don't have time to find the root cause for you but my gut says see what the menu is doing on page load and see if you are hiding it with JS.

If you are hiding it with JS and you have 0.2 second animations on every element on the site (which is not a good idea) with `html * {transition: all 0.2s ease;}` then this may cause an unnecessary repaint and put your LCP late.

### Actual problem.

The problem is we can argue slightly over the numbers but your site is indeed not particularly fast.

It weights 1.4 megabytes, which is high if you consider a mobile 3G connection may only be about 2 mega**bits** per second (so about 250 kilo**bytes** per second).

Also you have nearly a megabyte of uncompressed JavaScript to compile and execute on the site (about 250kb zipped).

That is a lot of heavy lifting on a mobile CPU.

Try and remove some of the JavaScript bloat, it is difficult when using something like elementor (as your site seems to do) however.

Also your speed will vastly improve if you fix your [critical rendering path and](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path) and defer your JavaScript that isn't essential for "above the fold" content to be rendered.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks so much for analysing the site and explaining all the concepts! I will read through everything carefully and make the changes needed! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Not a problem, hopefully it clears up why the times are longer on the mobile analysis and the things to tackle. One final thing I would say is focus less on the score and more on the items under "opportunities" and "diagnostics" as they give you loads of things to learn and try and implement. Good luck with the site!